# AKS (Azure Kubernetes Services) Pod cold start for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-functions, azure-aks

Currently I am trying to make existing Azure Function run on AKS. Azure Function itself loads evaluates a large machine learning model, so I am using App Service for it, so it won't go idle and will always keep model in memory, in order to quickly process incoming requests.

However, in AKS the default amount of running pods is 0. So when new request comes in (azure function processes reuquests from the queue), the AKS creates new pod from scratch, which takes a lot of time (because of the large model, which has to be loaded).

How can I set a minumum amount of pods that should be always running? Let's say, at least 1, so there won't be such long cold start.

Comment: have you tried using Deployment? You can specify the min number of replicas

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running from messages in a queue, I assume you are using KEDA. If so, you will have to set the `minReplicaCount` in your [`ScaledObject` definition](https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/concepts/scaling-deployments/#scaledobject-spec).